# Styling list item marker with inline style attribute

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

Is it possible to change the style of a list item marker using the inline style attribute of the list item?

I would like to write something like

```
<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li style="::marker {color: red}">Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

and the desired result is that only the number of the second item becomes red. For sure this can be achieved using a custom class e.g. as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
li.reddish::marker { 
  color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li class="reddish">Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

but my question is specifically about the style attribute of the list item node.

Comment: Does `style` attribute take selectors? No.

Comment: The style attribute takes CSS name-value pairs .. not another selector within it

Comment: BTW, you might use `:nth-child(2)` instead of class.

Comment: yes, but anyway that requires some "external" styling, while I would like to do something "internal" using only the `style` attribute of the specific node (actually, it might be any of the list items, not only the second one). I suspect that this is not possible using the `::marker` selector, since `style` does not take selectors (as you point out).

Answer (score 2):

Use css variable:

```css
li::marker {
  color: var(--marker, currentColor);
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li style="--marker: red;">Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need it inline, go further -- add more:

```html
<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li style="color: red"><span style="color:initial">Second</span></li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

const liStyles = {
paddingBlock: "10px",
lineHeight: "19px",
marker: { color: "#212223A" },
};

```
 <ul>
    <li>Was first released in 2013</li>
    <li style={liStyles}>Was originally created by Jordan Walke</li>
    <li style={liStyles}>Has over 100k stars on Github</li>
    <li style={liStyles}>Is maintained by Facebook</li>
    <li style={liStyles}>Is maintained by Facebook</li>
    <li style={liStyles}>
      Powers thousands of enterprise apps, including mobile apps
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I did this in trying to solve the problem of writing the cssinline with react

Comment: I don't see a react tag on the question